# Gridview: custom selector keeps blank

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to use a list selector for my gridview. I add it in xml via the android:listSelector attribute.

My selector looks like that:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_item_highlight" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selected_item_highlight" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

where the selected_item_highlight looks like that:

```
<shape 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
     <solid
        android:background="@color/ListHighlighting" />
</shape>
```

But the grid keeps blank. When I change the drawable attribute in the selector to drawable="@color/ListHighlighting" the whole grid - every item - get's highlighted in the color.

What's wrong?